# Clonal operator in Immune Clonal Strategy

Tags: machine-learning, papers, math, evolutionary-algorithms, biology

I was reading about Immune Clonal Strategy, specifically about Monoclonal operator from [Immunity clonal strategies](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4038253_Immunity_clonal_strategies), and it goes as follows:

[image]

Here $a_i $ is a point and $a_i = \{ x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m \}$.

I do not understand what $I_i$ really is, It seems like just copy $a_i$ for $q_i$ times or something like that, can someone please explain to me what is really happened here?